# Calendar.add changes time zone

Tags: java, time, calendar, timezone

In the following code, `range` equals `durationInDays` only when `range` is less than 30. If it is equal to 30 or greater, `durationInDays` is always `range - 1`

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
c.setTime(now);

int range = 35;
c.add(Calendar.DATE, range);
Date then = c.getTime();

Duration duration = Duration.between(now.toInstant(), then.toInstant());
int durationInDays = (int)duration.toDays();
```

When debugging this example, the variables are set as follows:

```
this = {CalTest@871} 
c = {GregorianCalendar@876} "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1522449516301,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Dublin",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=228,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Dublin,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=13,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=30,DAY_OF_YEAR=89,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=38,SECOND=36,MILLISECOND=301,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]"
now = {Date@877} "Fri Feb 23 23:38:36 GMT 2018"
range = 35
then = {Date@878} "Fri Mar 30 23:38:36 IST 2018"
duration = {Duration@879} "PT839H"
durationInDays = 34
```

Why does `then` have an IST timezone? This difference is the causing `duration` to be a little less than 35 days, rounding to 34.

Comment: Try printing the `Instant` values, and you'll see why.

Comment: You do know that `c.setTime(new Date());` is redundant, because `Calendar.getInstance()` has already initialized it now "now", right?

Comment: What is your default timezone? Print `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`

Comment: Do not mix the terrible old legacy classes Date/Calendar with the modern *java.time* classes. Avoid the legacy classes entirely. Use only *java.time*. Read the [*Oracle Tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) and start again. And search Stack Overflow before posting. These topics have been handled many many times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `then` hasn’t got IST timezone. A `Date` hasn’t got any time zone. `Date.toString` chooses a time zone, usually the JVM’s time zone setting, for generating the string only.

Looking at how your two `Date` objects are rendered in the debugger, one might wonder that it would appear they are rendered in two different time zones. They are not. Both are in Europe/Dublin time zone. As you are probably aware, Ireland with most of the EU switches to summer time (DST) on the last Sunday in March. Therefore, your date in February is in standard time, which in Ireland coincides with GMT, and therefore your string is rendered with `GMT` as “time zone”. On March 30, summer time is in effect, so the time zone is rendered as `IST` for Irish Summer Time this time. Edit: the transistion to summer time also accounts for the missing hour compared to your expected duration of 35 days (840 hours).

Edit: Since you can use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, I suggest you go all in and forget about the old-fashioned `Date` and `Calendar`. The modern API is so much nicer to work with, and you won’t need all the conversions any longer:

```
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin"));
    int range = 35;
    ZonedDateTime then = now.plusDays(range);
    Duration duration = Duration.between(now, then);
    int durationInDays = (int) duration.toDays();
```

The result is still PT839H and hence 34 days.

To obtain a duration in days that agrees with the number of days we added:

```
    int durationInDays = (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, then);
    System.out.println(durationInDays);
```

This prints

```
35
```

`Duration` is mostly for durations in hours, minutes and seconds. It does support days, but only days at 24 hours each, so gives the surprising result you saw when used across the summer time transition. `ChronoUnit.DAYS` on the other hand is exactly made for days. It sees that the two `ZonedDateTime` instances have the same time-of-day and therefore acknowledges a full 35 days between the two.